# How to assign a unique number from a table to another table row and change a flag in sql server

Tags: sql-server, flags

I have the following query that gets data from multiple tables as follows

```
SELECT TOP (1000)
      t.TicketID
      ,gg.[Name]
      ,FA.Phone      
  FROM #testtt gg inner join Market gm on gg.ID=gm.ID inner join MarketOption MO on gm.MarketID=MO.MarketID
  inner join TicketDetail TD  on TD.MarketOptionID=MO.MarketOptionID inner join Ticket t on t.TicketID=td.TicketID inner join Account FA  on t.AccountID=FA.AccountID
```

which gives me the following outcome

```
Ticket   |Name  | Number
35689    |Jane  |1259876325
78963    |Austin|7893256941
15896    |Raj   |4589623597
```

Now i have a Following Generator table that has about 500 rows

```
  ID| Number  | Flag
   1 | SD78569 | 0
   2 | 45G7y42 | 0
   3 | 7U5Gt56 | 0
   4 |F5Nhy45  | 0
   5 |153F786  | 0
```

what i am trying to achieve is that i want to assign a Number from the generator table with a flag of 0 to the query that was run,
for example this is my expected outcome

```
Ticket   |Name  | Phone     |Number      
35689    |Jane  |1259876325 |SD78569
78963    |Austin|7893256941 |7U5Gt56
15896    |Raj   |4589623597 |F5Nhy45
```

after it assigns a number the flag must change to 1 in the Generator table

```
Number  | Flag
SD78569 | 1
45G7y42 | 0
7U5Gt56 | 1
F5Nhy45 | 1
153F786 | 0
```

I am a bit confused as to how to achieve this as i dont know how i would join those tables since theres no criteria for me to join on and change the flag, your guidance will be appreciated.

I tried to do something like this where i added a temp table in

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#results') IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #results
END
SELECT TOP (1000)
          t.TicketID
          ,gg.[Name]
          ,FA.Phone 
          ,cast (null as nvarchar(25)) as GeneratorNumber // created a column to add the Number
into #Results    
      FROM #testtt gg inner join Market gm on gg.ID=gm.ID inner join MarketOption MO on gm.MarketID=MO.MarketID
      inner join TicketDetail TD  on TD.MarketOptionID=MO.MarketOptionID inner join Ticket t on t.TicketID=td.TicketID inner join Account FA  on t.AccountID=FA.AccountID
insert into  #results(GeneratorNumber)
select Number from dbo.Generator  // i tried copying it like this but it gives me an error "cannot insert the value Null into Column" and then i am not sure how to update the flag for the fields that where copied.
    where flag=0
```

//attempted

```
;With UpdateData AS (
Select GeneratorNumber,
ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY [GeneratorNumber] DESC) AS RN
FROM #results
)
 update #results  set GeneratorNumber=Number
 from dbo.Generator dg
 inner join UpdateData on UpdateData.RN=dg.ID
    select * from #results

Ticket   |Name  | Number    |GeneratedNumber
35689    |Jane  |1259876325 |SD78569
78963    |Austin|7893256941 |153F786
15896    |Raj   |4589623597 |SD78569
75663    |kate  |7893256452 |153F786  // as you can see its repeating the same numbers over and over i wanted it to use distinct numbers for each row
```

Comment: What is the criteria to join the tables? RowNumber will work?

Comment: Thats the problem is that i have no criteria to join it on

Comment: what have you tried so far..?

Comment: "i want to assign a Number" Rather than setting a flag to 1, set it to the ticket number that you assigned it to

Comment: there can be multiple of the same ticket number,but each ticket number can have the same generator number

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan how would i use RowNumber?

Comment: Make use of ROW_NUMBER() OVER() and derived tables together

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan i updated my question on what you suggested i try,am i doing something wrong? because its not adding the distinct values for each row